# Issue Embeding Youtube video in Angular JS without requiring page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, youtube

I am working on an ecommerce website and trying to add the ability for users to add youtube videos for their products on the product detail page. I have the code working other than the fact that the video does not show up until after a page refresh. I thought this would be a fairly simple project but I can not figure out how to get it to just load the iframe correctly without needing a page refresh. 
Here is my angular code right now:

```
controller("ProductDetailCtrl", function ($sce, productData, $scope, CartModel, $interval, $rootScope, EmailShareModel, $state, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    var detail = this;


    detail.product = productData;
    detail.product.videoHtml = "";
    if (productData.video !== null) {
      detail.product.videoHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"' + productData.video + '\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
```

And my Html:

```
<div ng-if ="detail.product.videoHtml" ng-bind-html="detail.product.videoHtml"></div>
```

As you can see I am simply binding the html which is an iframe to the view. And the controller is getting a json object from my rails api that contains all of the product data. productData.video is either null or is set to a string containing the youtube url. i.e. `https://www.youtube.com/embed/ANmmpnaWDto`
I have also tried using ng-src with an iframe in the html but I always run into this same issue with the refresh being needed. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Try using `$scope.$apply();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119538/angularjs-ng-bind-not-updating

Comment: Thank You for this suggestion I ended up using $timeout(); and it worked for me.